# How to set the state of a stateful widget from a child stateless widget

Tags: flutter, dart

Okay, so just to warn you, I'm 15 and I'm a complete flutter noob. This is my first ever project, so excuse the probably dumb question, and please go easy on me.
I have this stateful widget (`ride`) where the body is one of the child stateless widgets defined in `_children`. The if statement  just changes between the 1st and 2nd child widgets depending on if the user has connected a BT device (that part is irrelevant).
What I need to do is set the state from the inside of the `MaterialButton` found on ln 68 so that `ride` shows the `riding` stateless widget, but obviously I can't change the state from inside `startRide` because it's a stateless widget. How would I go about doing this?

```
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' ;
import 'results.dart';
import 'settings.dart';


class ride extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _rideState createState() => _rideState();
}

class _rideState extends State<ride> {
  int _currentState = 0;
  final List<Widget> _children = [
    notConnected(),
    startRide(),
    riding(),
  ];

  bool connected = checkBT(); // Function defined in settings.dart


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (connected == true){
      _currentState = 1;
      setState((){_currentState;});
    }
    return _children[_currentState];
  }
}

class notConnected extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(

      body: Container(
        height:180,
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(40, 0, 40, 0),
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            "Oops! Looks like your phone isn’t connected to your bluetooth device.",
            style:Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
        ),
      ),

    );
  }
}

class startRide extends StatelessWidget {
  AudioPlayer _audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();
  AudioCache player = AudioCache();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body:Center(
        child: Container(
          width: 200,
          height: 80,
          child: MaterialButton(
            onPressed:(){
              player.play("beeps.mp3");
              // I NEED TO SET THE STATE OF RIDE HERE
            },

            child: Text(
              "Start!",
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline1,
            ),
            color: Colors.red[500],
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(40.0)),


          ),
      ),
      ),
      ),
    );

  }

}

class riding extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(); //not finished writing this yet
  }
}
```

I'm probably going about doing this in completely the wrong way, but I've come from python so it's very different. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create callback, i.e passing function

Here is a sample code

```
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' ;
import 'results.dart';
import 'settings.dart';


class ride extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _rideState createState() => _rideState();
}

class _rideState extends State<ride> {
  int _currentState = 0;
  final List<Widget> _children = [
    notConnected(),
    startRide((){
      // you can setState((){}) here
    }),
    riding(),
  ];

  bool connected = checkBT(); // Function defined in settings.dart


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (connected == true){
      _currentState = 1;
      setState((){_currentState;});
    }
    return _children[_currentState];
  }
}

class notConnected extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(

      body: Container(
        height:180,
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(40, 0, 40, 0),
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            "Oops! Looks like your phone isn’t connected to your bluetooth device.",
            style:Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2,
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
        ),
      ),

    );
  }
}

class startRide extends StatelessWidget {
  AudioPlayer _audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();
  AudioCache player = AudioCache();
  Function callback;

  startRide(Function callback){
     this.callback = callback;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body:Center(
        child: Container(
          width: 200,
          height: 80,
          child: MaterialButton(
            onPressed:(){
              player.play("beeps.mp3");
              // I NEED TO SET THE STATE OF RIDE HERE
              // callback function
              callback();
            },

            child: Text(
              "Start!",
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline1,
            ),
            color: Colors.red[500],
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(40.0)),


          ),
      ),
      ),
      ),
    );

  }

}

class riding extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(); //not finished writing this yet
  }
}
```

Edit :- Test code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Test(),
    );
  }
}

class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Test createState() => _Test();
}

class _Test extends State<Test> {

  int current = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: root(),
    );
  }

  Widget root() {
    return Container(
      child: TestingStateless((){
        setState(() {
          current++;
          print(current);
        });
      }),
    );
  }
}

// ignore: must_be_immutable
class TestingStateless extends StatelessWidget{
  Function func;

  TestingStateless(Function func){
    this.func = func;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: (){
        func();
      },
      child: Container(
        height: 50,
        color: Colors.green,
        child: Text('TESTING'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: how would this be triggered from the ```MaterialButton``` in ```startRide```?

Comment: search for the function callback in your startRide class

Comment: Okay so I implemented what you said. I don't know if I did it wrong but where I have put ```setState```, I get an error saying ```The instance member 'setState' can't be accessed in an initializer.```
Here is the code I wrote for that section:
```
  final List<Widget> _children = [
    notConnected(),
    startRide((){
      setState;{
        _currentState = 2; 
      }
    }),
    riding(),
  ];```

Comment: @ArduinoBobby i created a test code and its working fine. If you can update you whole code, it might help people to find error. I've edited and pasted my test code(example) for you. You can give it a look.